# How to search in specific files matching a pattern

Tags: shell, wildcards, search, recursive

How can I find a word in specific files matching a pattern. e.g. searching for `version` in `CMake*` files recursively found in the current directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to see the file name and line number, POSIXly:

```
find . -name 'CMake*' -type f -exec grep -nF /dev/null version {} +
```

(you don't want to use `;` here which would run one `grep` per file). That's the standard equivalent of the GNUism:

```
find . -name 'CMake*' -type f -print0 | xargs -r0 grep -nHF {} +
```

`find` (in the first), `xargs` (in the second) will pass as many arguments to `grep` as possible without exceeding the limit on the number of arguments you can pass to a command. When doing that splitting, it could happen that for the last run, only one argument be passed to `grep` in which case `grep` wouldn't print the file name. That's why you need `/dev/null` there (or `-H` with GNU `grep`).

With `-type f`, we're only considering regular files (not devices, symlinks, pipes, directories...).

If you want to use GNUisms, you could use GNU `grep` ability to descend a directory tree:

```
 grep -rHnF --include='CMake*' version .
```

You don't want to use `-R` as that causes `grep` to follow symlinks when descending the directory tree and read from devices, fifos, sockets...

That version is safer and more efficient, but not portable.

Answer (score 3):

Use `find` to select the files then grep to search in the files:

```
find . -name "CMake*" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -F version
```

by using `xargs`, you do not have `grep` started for each and every file found.

Answer (score 3):

Just to show that you can do this without having to enlist the help of `find`. You can make use of `grep`'s ability to recurse the filesystem too. Assuming your version of `grep` has the `-R` switch:

```
$ grep -R version | awk -F: '/CMake.*:/ {print $1}'
```

#### Example

I created some sample data which included files named CMake1-3 which contained the string `version`, as well as a file named CMake0 which did not. I also created 2 files named `afile` that also contained the string `version`.

```
$ tree .
.
|-- CMake1
|-- dir1
|   |-- dirA1
|   |   `-- CMake1
|   |-- dirA2
|   `-- dirA3
|-- dir2
|   |-- dirA1
|   |   `-- CMake0
|   |-- dirA2
|   |   |-- afile
|   |   `-- CMake2
|   `-- dirA3
`-- dir3
    |-- dirA1
    |-- dirA2
    |   `-- afile
    `-- dirA3
        `-- CMake3
```

Now when I run the above command:

```
$ grep -R version | awk -F: '/CMake.*:/ {print $1}'
CMake1
dir2/dirA2/CMake2
dir3/dirA3/CMake3
dir1/dirA1/CMake1
```

#### Details

The above commands produces a list like this from `grep`:

```
$ grep -R version 
CMake1:version
dir2/dirA2/CMake2:version
dir2/dirA2/afile:version
dir3/dirA2/afile:version
dir3/dirA3/CMake3:version
dir1/dirA1/CMake1:version
```

And `awk` is used to find all the strings that contain `CMake.*:` and to split these strings on a colon (`:`), and to return just the first field from this split, i.e., the path of the name of a corresponding `CMake*` file.

#### 2 grep's + PCRE

More modern versions of grep will often include what's called [PCRE - Perl Compatible Regular Exprssions](http://www.pcre.org/). So you could use 2 `grep` commands, with the 2nd one using PCRE to extract just the path portion of the file, omitting the trailing `:version` bit of the string from the 1st `grep`.

#### Example

```
$ grep -R version | grep -Po '.*CMake.*(?=:version)'
CMake1
dir2/dirA2/CMake2
dir3/dirA3/CMake3
dir1/dirA1/CMake1
```

The `-o` will return just the matching portion, while `-P` is what enables PCRE. Within the regular expression we're using a lookahead, (`?=...`), at the end to select only strings that have a trailing `:version`. This lookahead is only to help align our pattern, it isn't included in the results we return, nor is it part of the actual pattern we're grepping for, i.e. `CMake.*`.

#### Line numbers

You can also include the switch `-n` to the first `grep` so that the line number where the string `version` was encountered can also be included in the output.

#### Example

```
$ grep -Rn version | grep -Po '.*CMake.*(?=:version)'
CMake1:1
dir2/dirA2/CMake2:9
dir3/dirA3/CMake3:1
dir1/dirA1/CMake1:1
```

To make the first example work you'd need to change the `awk` commands slightly:

```
$ grep -Rn version | awk -F: '/CMake.*:/ {print $1":"$2}'  
CMake1:1
dir2/dirA2/CMake2:9
dir3/dirA3/CMake3:1
dir1/dirA1/CMake1:1
```

The first example gives you the opportunity though to move the line number around, since we've already parsed it into a separate field via `awk`.

#### Example

Here we can put the number first.

```
$ grep -Rn version | awk -F: '/CMake.*:/ {print $2":"$1}'  
1:CMake1
9:dir2/dirA2/CMake2
1:dir3/dirA3/CMake3
1:dir1/dirA1/CMake1
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to have the file name and line number in which the word was found in the search result as well?

Comment: @Meysam - sure, you can turn on the switch `-n` which will include the line number. The examples I've provided should still work with this options turned on. `grep -Rn version | ...`.

Comment: @Meysam - see updates to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name "CMake*" -exec grep -H version {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of find an grep:

```
find . -name "Cmake*" -exec grep version {} \;
```

The example searches recursively from current directory and executes grep on the matching files.